# Generating dynamic forms on the fly in the Django Template

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms

I have a Django template (html file).It contains a drop-down selector which has many options.On selecting each option a pre-defined form is shown on the browser.Every such form has a pre-defined fields.

For ex., on selecting About option, Form will be -

```
Name - 
Age -
```

And on selecting Education option, Form will be -

```
University - 
CGPA -
```

Now What is the best way to implement this functionality?

**Format 1** - On selecting any option, I make a Ajax call to the server and return a json of fields to be shown.

**Format 2** - I hard-code several forms in the template and make their visiblity - true according to the option selected.(I am not convinced by this)

**Format 3** - Any new solution which I am looking for here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is how i implemented it few days back:

Send ajax call to the server of what form you need and then send the from back to the template in HTML form.

```
form = Yourform()
form = form.as_p()
return HttpResponse(form)
```

This will return your form in HTML format. Now all you need to do is replace your container with this new form.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note, since @akg mentioned that the forms could be totally different, the method in views.py that processes the form has to determine what kind of form is filled out in the template.

Comment: for that @akg can use simple if else condition. I thought this was important part here. :D

Comment: I'm not making any comment on the "important part", I just want to point out that a form from the template itself could not tell the backend which form should be used. You must have something else in the `POST` data to tell the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who is going to maintain it later on!

If you are going to query the backend for the fields then whoever wants to add new fields to the form, has to access the backend code and insert it there. Generally, not everybody has access to it! And that person needs to know Django. Also, with ajax you are still making a HTTP request, although on localhost, which can have slight lag compared to hard-coded forms

Rather, You can probably use django templating engine to its fullest like, template inheritance and stuff, to reduce your code redundancy and keep the forms in the front-end itself! That way if a front-end person has to add something new, he can do it in HTML!

If at all you have thousands of fields in a form which are too much to type or maintain, then you can make an ajax request. Or else keeping in front-end works well!

Hope this helps!

(Whoever plans to downvote the answer, please do mention the reason too, for downvoting)